# Copy string and increment version

Tags: javascript

For example if we have string `str` and I copy it it will be `str_1`, `str_2`, `str_3` and so on..

If I copy `str_2` then it will be `str_2_1`, `str_2_2` and so on.

I have following logic but it does not work..
It should return 'Test2_5' (because Test2 AND Test2_4 already exists) but it returns 'Test2_4'

```js
function createName(nameToCopy) {
  var i;
  var version = 1;

  var nameCopiesArr = ["Test2", "Test2_2",
    "Test2_3",
    "Test2_4",
    "Test2_2_2",
    "Test2_3_1",
    "Test2_2_1_2",
    "Test2_2_3"
  ];

  if (nameCopiesArr && nameCopiesArr.length > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < nameCopiesArr.length; i++) {
      var indexes = nameCopiesArr[i].lastIndexOf('_') ? nameCopiesArr[i].match(/\d+$/) : 0
      if (indexes) {
        version = indexes[indexes.length - 1];
        version = parseInt(version) + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  p = nameToCopy + '_' + version;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = p;
  return p;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createName('Test2')">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: where do you know, if the copy is starting with one, or just a counting copy?

Comment: please add **why** with given `'Test2'` it should return `'Test2_5'`. what is the logic behind that?

Comment: Perhaps because rest2 AND test2_4 already exists

Comment: because it is the requirement as explained above. I clicked on 'Test2' then it will generate 'Test2_1' then next time it will be 'Test2_2','Test2_3' like that... Currently our array have 'Test2_4' as highest number so after that increment it by 1 version so it will be 'Test2_5'

Comment: You increment the 3 in `Test2_2_3` instead of the 4 in `Test2_4` because of the `.lastIndexOf('_')` - you need to count the `_`s - they have to be as few as possible

Comment: yes but not able to get that count.

Comment: nameCopiesArr[i].split('_').length

Comment: actually I am thinking that, the way I am trying to achieve this, is wrong.. Don't know any other way it can be done..

Answer (score 1):

You could search for all string which starts with the given name and a dash and an ending number. Then take the max number of ending and return the given string with an incremented version.

```js
function createName(nameToCopy) {
    var copies = ["Test2", "Test2_2", "Test2_3", "Test2_4", "Test2_2_2", "Test2_3_1", "Test2_2_1_2", "Test2_2_3"],
        filtered = copies.filter(/./.test.bind(new RegExp(nameToCopy + '_' + '\\d+$'))),
        version = filtered.reduce((v, s) => Math.max(v, +s.match(/\d+$/)[0]), 0);

    return nameToCopy + '_' + ++version;
}

console.log(['Test2', 'Test', 'Test2_2'].map(createName));
```

More traditional

```js
function createName(nameToCopy) {
    var copies = ["Test2", "Test2_2", "Test2_3", "Test2_4", "Test2_2_2", "Test2_3_1", "Test2_2_1_2", "Test2_2_3"],
        regexp = new RegExp(nameToCopy + '_' + '\\d+$'),
        version = 0,
        i, v;

    for (i = 0; i < copies.length; i++) {
        if (regexp.test(copies[i])) {
            v = +copies[i].match(/\d+$/)[0];
            if (v > version) {
                version = v;
            }
        }
    }
        
    return nameToCopy + '_' + (version + 1);
}

console.log(['Test2', 'Test', 'Test2_2'].map(createName));
```

Comment: too good.. wanted to do something like this but don't know when I will reach till that level.. :-)

Comment: hey nina actually 'copies'  is array of object in my actual code, for simplicity I gave it as array. so now i am not able to run this code for array of object. i don't understand how should i call 

filtered = copies.filter(/./.test.bind(new RegExp(nameToCopy + '_' + '\\d+$'))),
        version = filtered.reduce((v, s) => Math.max(v, +s.match(/\d+$/)[0]), 0);

Comment: then takle the second approach and use the property, like `copies[i].prop` instead of `copies[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, or why, so I can't really comment on your code. Just note that it is not too efficient, and not too understandable. And as a side note, your html doesn't call the code you wrote.

to answer your question of why it returns 'Test2_4' : your code loops through the hard coded values you put into the nameCopiesArr, and the version variable keeps the number of the current name + 1. And then you overwrite this with the result from the next entry in the array. Since the last entry in the array is 'Test2_2_3', you grab the last number there - which is 3 - and add 1 to that, so after your last iteration the version variable holds the value of 4 - and this is what you return.

Answer (score 0):

I update your code to test the number of the '_' char and if the current string contains the given input.

```
function createName(nameToCopy) {
  var i;
  var version = 1;
  var nameToCopy_Nb = (nameToCopy.match(/_/g) || []).length; //number of the '_' char

  var nameCopiesArr = ["Test2", "Test2_2",
    "Test2_3",
    "Test2_4",
    "Test2_2_2",
    "Test2_3_1",
    "Test2_2_1_2",
    "Test2_2_3"
  ];

  if (nameCopiesArr && nameCopiesArr.length > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < nameCopiesArr.length; i++) {
      var item_Nb = (nameCopiesArr[i].match(/_/g) || []).length;//number of the '_' char
      if (nameCopiesArr[i].indexOf(nameToCopy) !== -1 && item_Nb === nameToCopy_Nb + 1) {
        var indexes = nameCopiesArr[i].lastIndexOf('_') ? nameCopiesArr[i].match(/\d+$/) : 0
        if (indexes) {
          version = indexes[indexes.length - 1];
          version = parseInt(version) + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  p = nameToCopy + '_' + version;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = p;
  return p;
}
```

But the answer of @Nina is good and probably the shortest !!! (I upvote her answer)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2yywLh8/3/)